# Deactivate directory listing for all but LAN htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'd like to deactivate the directory listing with htaccess for all but my local IPs.

This is working fine, but just for one `IP` address:

```
    # deactivate directory listing if not coming from local
    Options -Indexes
    <If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} == '192.168.188.44' ">
      Options +Indexes
    </If>
```

How would I do it for all `IP` addresses coming from `192.168.*` ?

I am using `Apache2 2.4.4` on my Windows and currently `2.2.2` on my ubuntu server.
Obviously the code block above wont work before `Apache2 2.4`.
So it would be nice if some snippet would work on both systems.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via `mod_rewrite` in both older/newer Apache versions.

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: I had tested it before posting. Make sure this is first rule and placed in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess `

Comment: Found the error: I am connecting to this server through my router (no VPN, via dyndns) and so it must be thinking that I am from my local network.
I checked your snippet against a live server of mine and it is working correctly, therefore your answer is correct.

Comment: Or.. I checked the htaccess against an online tester. It says REMOTE_ADDR is not available. But I dont understand?         root@raspberrypi:/var/www# apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Server built:   Mar 10 2013 05:34:48

root@raspberrypi:/var/www# a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled

How can this be? Any idea?

Comment: Online tester is not the way to test this rule. Test it on you web server (I have already tested it)

Comment: OK its the IP address. REMOTE_ADDR is a local LAN IP, thats why it wont work. (Checked it with PHP) Stupid DYNDNS :D. Thank you anyway. Have to think of something else then. :)

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 # deactivate directory listing if not coming from local
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.0\.10$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [F]
</IfModule>

Is now working in my special case. Thank you for your help.